# How to find why midnight commander is too slow when connecting to a specific server?

Tags: networking, network-speed

I have a quite strange problem regarding the connecting to a remote server.

The problem is very annoying when I'm using Midnight Commander (`mc`), just to scroll or inside the editor.

Overall there is a **big lag between when I press a key and I get the response**.

Now here is the current list of investigations:

#### Network speed

```
26 packets transmitted, 26 received, 0% packet loss, time 25033ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 154.538/158.928/178.473/5.057 ms
```

#### Bandwidth

I tried to transfer a 50MB zip file from my machine to the server via SSH(scp) and I got an average speed of **>1Mbps** (initially the speed was around ~150kbps but grew fast)

#### Machine load

```
top - 02:36:09 up 217 days, 5 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.22, 0.55, 0.40
Tasks:  75 total,   2 running,  73 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2053312k total,  1940624k used,   112688k free,    22848k buffers
Swap:   392184k total,    12556k used,   379628k free,   742936k cached
```

Note: this is a virtual machine and I asked IT if there is load issue with the guest and they reported that everything is ok.

What else could cause this and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you sniff your ssh traffic when using mc? If there's lots of tcp packet loss/retransmit - it will show you that problem is with network congestion.